# Resizing a html5 canvas with the "<select></select>" form

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been trying to create a canvas element that you can resize with the value of a "select form". I'd prefer to use only  Javascript to accomplish this. I feel like I'm missing a very small detail somewhere.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 550;
canvas.height = 300;
drawScreen();

formElement = document.getElementById("height");
formElement.addEventListener('change', heightCanged, true);

formElement = document.getElementById("width");
formElement.addEventListener('change', widthCanged, false);

function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
//html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<h3>Height</h3>

<select id="height">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<h3>Width</h3>

<select id="width">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8ma4evLp/1/

Comment: Your JSfiddle is useless. It doesn't have nearly enough of the code. Where is your drawScreen function?

Comment: For some reason the person edited this post removed it. If you look at the actual post you can see the functions.

Comment: Not true, `drawScreen` is not defined in your post

Comment: So sorry thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were are couple of things that were off, looked like some function names misspelled, and the big one, you where using the name attribute on the select element, but you were using the `getElementById()` to grab it in JavaScript.  Here is an updated and working example.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 550;
canvas.height = 300;
drawScreen();

formElement = document.getElementById("height");
formElement.addEventListener('change', heightChanged, true);

formElement = document.getElementById("width");
formElement.addEventListener('change', widthChanged, false);

function widthChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.width = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function heightChanged(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  canvas.height = target.value;
  drawScreen();
}

function drawScreen() {
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<h3>Height</h3>
<select name="Height" id='height'>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>


<h3>Width</h3>
<select name="Width" id='width'>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the call to drawScreen (since it's not defined) it should work just fine: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ma4evLp/2/)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var heightSelect = document.getElementById("height");
var widthSelect = document.getElementById("width");

canvas.width = 550;
canvas.height = 300;
//drawScreen();

heightSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    canvas.height = this.value;
});

widthSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    canvas.width = this.value;
});
```

```css
#canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<h3>Height</h3>
<select name="height" id="height">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>


<h3>Width</h3>
<select name="Width" id="width">
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
</select>
```

Comment: For some reason when I check your fiddle the opposite happens. For example if I changed the height to a bigger size it gets smaller.

Comment: The sizes I specify in the select options are smaller than the original canvas size.

Comment: Oh okay, I had only glanced at it. Is there a difference between defining the drawScreen function and not defining it when comes to resizing the canvas element?

Comment: If you call a function that hasn't been defined the runtime will stop executing the code. So in this case if `drawScreen()` is called before the calls to set the width and height the width and height won't get set since the execution has stopped at the undefined method call.